# Modal image not working for multiple images

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4

I am using Modal to display multiple images in a popup box, It's working fine for the first image but not for all images getting fetched by PHP While Loop.

Can Anyone help to Display all fetched images with Modal?

Code:

```
    <?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = $id");
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    
    if($id){
    while($img = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>                
        
    
    <tr>
        <td><img style="height:100px;" id="myImg" src='<?php echo "uploads/" . $img['img_url']; ?>'>
                    
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
                    </td>
                    
                </tr>
                
                <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Images</th>
                    <
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            </tbody>
          </table>

    <script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    
    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    img.onclick = function(){
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = this.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
    
    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    
    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() { 
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IDs must be unique within the scope of an HTML document - by outputting the same IDs multiple times in your loop, you are violating that.

Comment: @CBroe Can you help me with code to get new id for every new image?